# Где найти описание протокола SSL proxy?

Tags: java, c#, c++, ssl, proxy

Хочу написать SSL proxy. Может быть у кого-нибудь есть описание протокола?

Или хотя бы, есть понятный пример исходного кода на языках С++/С#/Java?

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246 https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL

Comment: мне сам ssl не нужен... может правильнее назвать HTTPS PROXY